# How to loop in PHP and display all rows

Tags: php

So I have this problem in looping in PHP, I can't seem to display, it only displays the first row. I want to display all 18 places and at the same time all places have different counts/data each. I think I'm missing a lot in PHP.

```
 //This part of code displays the names and counts the met conditions
$sql = "SELECT   b.name as brgy0,(SELECT COUNT(brgy_id) FROM tbl_fire_info where YEAR(date_of_report)=$year AND MONTH(date_of_report)=$smonth and status=1 AND brgy_id=b.barangayID) as cnt FROM tbl_barangay as b";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

      $numData = $row['cnt']; 
      $brgyData = $row['brgy0'];


 //This part of code displays the data in the graph, I decided to loop it 18 times
   new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
       labels: ['<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo $haz;} ?>'], 
       datasets: [ //barangays
           <?php
             if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
               while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
               {
                 label: "<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo $brgyData;} ?>", 
                  backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
                  data: [<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo $numData;} ?>]
               }      
           <?php
              echo ",";
              }
            }else {
                   echo "0 results";
                  }
            ?>
                ]
                  },
                   options: {
                   title: {
                   display: true,
                   text: 'Number of reports'
                          }
                        }
           });
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches 1 row.  Look at the manual for examples on looping http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Your problem is probably that there is no code in here at all that is a looping construct. `for`, `foreach`, `while`, etc.